# Is there any app used for uploading in Pinax?

Tags: django, pinax

Is there any app used for uploading in Pinax?

Comment: Do you want to enable upload from the admin interface or do you want to enable site users to upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different apps included in Pinax that are used for uploading different things: avatars, photos, attachments. The first two are fairly specific but django-attachments is fairly generic if your goal is to attach files to objects.

We also will probably add django-adminfiles in 0.9

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the form and everything yourself (or find a generic django app that does what you want).  Pinax is not a CMS where you just attach apps and never actually have to write any code.  It gives you an already made social networking site so that you can write the parts that you are interesting in writing (this sounds like something you want to write).